# Text in Textarea is not scrolling with ng-repeat with ionic- angular js

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When  i using  textarea below the ng-repeat in angular js - ionic . The text area is not working properly  and some time lost it focus also.  Please provide me solution for that  this is my code :

```
                <div class="title">Comments</div>
                <ul class="comment_list">
                    <li ng-repeat="x in comments ">
                        <a><img no-image ng-src="{{profile_img_path.image_url_tiny+x.User.image}}" alt="" class="pro_img"></a>
                        <div class="pro_deatil" >
                            <h2> {{x.User.name}} </h2>
                            <p>{{x.CommentDish.comment}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pro_like" >

                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

                <div class="comment">
                    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="10" ng-model="comment_data.comment" placeholder="Enter Comment" class="post_txt_area" overflow-scroll="true"></textarea>
                    <div> <a  ng-click="postComment()" class="event_btn">Comment</a> </div>
                </div>
```

Please help me if anyone has solution for this issue....

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle with your problem

Comment: Hello shammon.. thanks for your response.. but it is device touch issue.... actully the problem is when i tap on text area and write something in there then it lost focus sometimes and also not scrolling with large texts..   but when i use text area in any page that is not containing 'ng-repeat'  it works fine...